Can't get a "before build" target to work with MSBuild
I have a simple hello world console app with top level statements as follows:
Console.WriteLine("Hello world");

I would like to experiment with automatically executing targets before the build process, so I edited the CSPROJ file as follows;
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="BEFORE BUILD TARGET" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>

I tried dotnet build MyProj.csproj with verbosity levels all the way up to diagnostic. However I can't get the message text to appear.
What am I doing wrong here?
EDIT
It looks like @Neil T's suggestion worked, and now my output looks like this when I run dotnet build MyProj.csproj
$ MsBuildTargets  dotnet build .\MsBuildTargets.csproj
MSBuild version 17.9.8+610b4d3b5 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  MsBuildTargets -> C:\Users\Amine.Aboufirass\Desktop\TEMP\CommunicateWithCoFlowAPI\MsBuildTargets\bin\Debug\net8.0\MsBuildTargets.dll
  BEFORE BUILD TARGET

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:08.36

To me it looks like the message text appears after the project is built and not before? Or am I reading this wrong?

Glad to hear this worked. Regarding your edit and supplementary question: I would suggest you append /flp:v=diag;logfile=MyLog.log (or similar) to your dotnet build command. This will output a full build log to your project folder. You will be able to inspect/search this to see exactly where your message task is executing - it will be logged as something like Task "Message" (TaskId:xx) Task Parameter:Text=BEFORE BUILD TARGET (TaskId:xx). You can read more about logging options on this question.

The two messages, "Determining projects to restore..." and "All projects are up-to-date for restore.", are from the NuGet Restore operation which is performed before the build. Your message is after the Restore which is expected.

Your target name is "BeforeBuild":
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">

To quote the Microsoft documentation here:

Be sure to use different names than the predefined targets (for example, the custom build target here is CustomAfterBuild, not AfterBuild), since those predefined targets are overridden by the SDK import which also defines them. Refer to the table at the end of this article for a list of predefined targets.

Try changing your target name to (e.g.) "CustomBeforeBuild" to avoid this somewhat subtle pitfall.

Put your target before the BeforeBuild target, not the Build target, e.g. <Target Name="CustomTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">. This is especially important if you are adding or removing items from some of the common item collections.

I think that worked, but please see edits to the original question
